# How to detect permission's permanent deny in Android 11?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11

In Android 11, when user select "deny" option for more than once for any permission request, then system will mark it as "Permanently denied".Once permanently denied, user has to enable in settings.From this time `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` start's to return `false`

Three options are available for permission window , "Deny","Allow All time","Allow only this time". But in settings "Deny","Allow all the time","Ask every time" are present.

How to find when user selects "Ask me every time" from settings, because, `checkSelfPermission()` returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`,and `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` return `false`. In this time I want to show permission window, instead of move to settings. **Something similar to google map permission**

Comment: I believe that is intentional behavior, I would show a `Toast` message anytime the user deny the permission: "To reactivate this feature, please go to app settings to grant XX permmission."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the new ActivityResultsContract you can do this in the following manner

```
    private val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
        ) { result: MutableMap<String, Boolean> ->
            val deniedList: List<String> = result.filter {
                !it.value
            }.map {
                it.key
            }

            when {
                deniedList.isNotEmpty() -> {
                    val map = deniedList.groupBy { permission ->
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) DENIED else EXPLAINED
                    }
                    map[DENIED]?.let {
                        // request denied , request again
                    }
                    map[EXPLAINED]?.let {
                        //request denied ,send to settings 

                    }

                }
                else -> {
                   //All request are permitted
                }
            }
        }
```

In OnCreate()[Make sure you ask permission in OnCreate , else application will crash] , ask the permission :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)
    }
```

Ask requiredPermissions in the following manner :

```
private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
)
```

Comment: Working. Thanks

Comment: what is DENIED else EXPLAINED here, please share your imports

Comment: Both are constant variables to define which permission is Denied and which is explained. Just declare as const val DENIED = "denied" and const val EXPLAINED="explained"

Comment: This does not work if the user dismissed the permission dialog.

Comment: Hey @Kairat, the above code wasn't designed to meet your requirements, it does the task asked in the question above. You need to design the code for your own usecase, if met with any issue raise a question and ping me here

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is one more scenario:
if the user let you request the permission but don't chose any option and dismissed the dialog by tapping outside, the request finishes with denied and `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` returns false.
That is the exact same behaviour as if the user selects don't ask again.
the permission where requested once, it results in denied and we should not show a explanation.

therefore we have to track if `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` has returned true for once. if it switches back to false its denied permanent.

Comment: Where is the `shouldExplainPermissionRational()` function? I cant find it... did you mean `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`?

Comment: Yes, sry. Corrected that one

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method in your activity (Camera permission is used in this example):

```
private fun requestPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            //Permission is denied
        } else {
            //ask permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will sometimes trigger if permissions have only been denied once.

Answer (score -2):

You only need to check the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() after user deny the permission

```
val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted: Boolean ->
    if (isGranted) {

    } else {
        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.YOUR_RUNTIME_PERMISSION)){
            //user hasn't denied permission permanently
        }else{
            //user has denied permanently,
            //you should try to redirect user to settings
            //to ask user grant it manually
        }
    }
}
requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.YOUR_RUNTIME_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale function has 2 parameters, not one.

Comment: shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale could also return false when user is dismissing the permission dialog.